# Django Cookie with Login function

Tags: django, cookies

I'm trying to set my `first cookie` with Django when users are logged on my application.
When user is logged, the template is well-displayed but none cookie in my application which is named : `Cookie`

My function looks like :

```
def Login(request):
    error = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ConnexionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  
            if user:  
                login(request, user)      
                toto = GEDCookie(request)                              
                return render(request, 'Home_Homepage.html', {'toto':toto})

            else: 
                error = True

    else:
        form = ConnexionForm()

    return render(request, 'Authentication_Homepage.html', locals())

@csrf_exempt
def GEDCookie(request):

    SID = Logger.login("test", "10test")
    response = HttpResponse("Cookie") 
    response.set_cookie('Cookie', SID, max_age=None)

    return response
```

I missed something in my script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how you use cookies at all.

Inside your Login view, you're calling a separate view - GEDCookie that returns an HTTP response. But instead of returning that response directly to the user, which would set the cookie, you're for some reason trying to insert it in a template. That doesn't make sense.

If you want to set a cookie in your login view, you need to do so on the response that you return to the user.

Note also that after a successful login (or other post), you should always *redirect*, not display a template directly. So:

```
if user:  
    login(request, user)      
    response = redirect('home')
    response.set_cookie('whatever')
    return response
```

Finally, you almost certainly don't need a cookie here in any case. If you want to store data related to the current user, use the session.

Answer (score 1):

As you can clearly see that you are not attaching your cookie to your real response, you are passing it as the context in render function which is an issue.

```
def Login(request):
    error = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ConnexionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                SID = Logger.login("test", "10test")
                response = render(request, 'Home_Homepage.html', {})
                response.set_cookie('Cookie', SID, max_age=None)
                return  response

            else:
                error = True

    else:
        form = ConnexionForm()

    return render(request, 'Authentication_Homepage.html', locals())
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works with your answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie Please refer this link for individual arguments of inbuilt function.

Create signal.py in app. where your user model is present or add in main project directory and Add below snippet in signal.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, pre_delete, post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.dispatch import Signal
from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in # it signal for post login 
from django.shortcuts import render

@receiver(user_logged_in) # Decorator of receiving signal while user going to logged in
def post_login(sender, user, request, response, **kwargs):
    response.set_cookie('team', 'india') # This will set cookie
    return response
```

In given snippet, default response will come in argument, so direct redirect to that response, if you want to change then render other template using render/redirect django.shortcuts methods like below,

```
response = render(request, 'base.html', {})
```